Smooth structures on codimension-2 Thom-Mather stratifications
Consider a Thom-Mather stratified space with one singular stratum of codimension two:
$$
\rho : M \to [0,\infty), D = \\{ x \in M \mid \rho(x) = 0 \\}.
$$
Since $D$ is codimension two, the real blow-up $p : X \to M$ restricts to an $S^1$ fiber bundle on the boundary
$$
S^1 \hookrightarrow \partial X \xrightarrow{p} D.
$$
This suggests we may construct "Cartesian coordinates" on $M \setminus D$, namely $x_1 \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \rho \cos \theta$ and $x_2 \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \rho \sin \theta$ (where $\theta$ is the coordinate on $S^1$ valued in $[0,2\pi)$).
Do these coordinates extend to a smooth structure on $M$?
While I do not see why the answer would be no, this seems to lead to oddly strong conclusions. For example, we could(?) show that any even-dimensionally-stratified Thom-Mather space has a smooth structure, by applying a postive answer to this question inductively, from the highest codimension stratum upward.
Any literature to answer this question would be appreciated.
